# How can I move the datalabel in top right in variable pie chart

Tags: highcharts, pie-chart

How can I  move the below datalabel football in the **top right** of the variable pie chart instead of showing in bottom. I tried these options

**alignTo: 'connectors'  or alignTo: 'toPlotEdges'**

But nothing worked for me. Any help will be appreciated

```
var total = 80;
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
      type: 'variablepie',
      height: 370,
      marginBottom: 50
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Football vs cricket',
      align: 'center',
      y: -5,
      verticalAlign: 'bottom',
      style: {
        fontFamily: 'proxima_nova_bold',
        fontSize: '20px',
        fontWeight: 'normal',
        color: '#8d99ab',
      }
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: '&nbsp;&nbsp;' + total + '<br/> Total',
      useHTML: true,
      verticalAlign: 'middle',
      y: -20
    },
    xAxis: {
      labels: {
        rotation: 0
      }
    },
    plotOptions: {
      variablepie: {
        size: 220,
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          connectorColor: '#979797',
          useHTML: true,
          formatter: function () {
            var key;
            if(this.key == 'football'){
              key = 'as football / Lionel Messi';
            }else if(this.key == 'cricket'){
              key = 'as cricket / Sachin Tendulkar';
            }else{
              key = this.key;
            }
            return '<span class=cls1>' + this.y + '</span>' + '<span class=cls2>' +  key + '</span>';
          }
        },
        showInLegend: true,
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      formatter: function() {
        return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.y +' %';
      }
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: false
    },
     series: [{
      minPointSize: 10,
      innerSize: '70%',
      zMin: 0,
      data: [{name: "football", y: 71, z: 30}, {name: "cricket", y: 2, z: 18}]
    }]
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/anikettiwari/Lr3zy8qc/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can try to implement one of the options showed here: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/pie-datalabels-alignment

Or use the **render** callback and set the y position of this particular label manually.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2oskhmnd/

```
  events: {
    render() {
        let chart = this;

        chart.series[0].points[0].dataLabel.attr({y: 10});
        chart.series[0].points[0].connector.hide();
    }
  }
```

Unfortunately, this solution requires to render the custom connector to moved dataLabel. You can do it by using some of the methods shown in the above link (pie-datalabels-alignment) or by using SVGRenderer tool to render a path: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#path

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render

Comment: In your case, data labels are overlapping with the pie chart and one connector is missing

Comment: @AniketShivamTiwari Yeah, I mendtioned that this solution requires to render a custom connector. What do you have in mind by saying that `data labels are overlapping with the pie chart`?

Comment: The solution which you have provided in that data labels are overlapping. And most importantly the connectors are getting hide. What I wanted to achieve is both the connectors should be on top without overlapping. And same applies to data labels

Comment: There is no other options to render the connector automatically for these requirements. You can create a custom connector by using the `SVGRenderer` tool. Here is a basic demo of how to create a custom connector: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3dsujyga/